# How to read text file with uneven number of columns with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the file with following format:

```
really:1 christensen:1 scariest:1 many_of:1 label:positive
varied_experiences:1 experiences_from:1 island_resident:1 many_and:1 label:positive
scariest:1 many_of:1 label:negative
```

The last column is the label of polarity, with values negative or positive. The other columns before it are the bag-of-words representation of the corresponding paragraph. How can I read the file into a data frame with two columns that the first is the bag-of-word string and the second is the label?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many rows have output? `3` or `10`?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for you reply. But I am a little confused of what you mean by "output". Are you asking how many rows have the "label"? If then all the rows have labels

Comment: please see answer with 3 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) only:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""really:1 christensen:1 scariest:1 many_of:1 label:positive
varied_experiences:1 experiences_from:1 island_resident:1 many_and:1 label:positive
scariest:1 many_of:1 label:negative"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep=r" label:",
                 header=None, 
                 names=['bag','label'], 
                 engine='python')
print (df)
                                                 bag     label
0       really:1 christensen:1 scariest:1 many_of:1   positive
1  varied_experiences:1 experiences_from:1 island...  positive
2                              scariest:1 many_of:1   negative
```

More general solution, which [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) by last whitespace:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""really:1 christensen:1 scariest:1 many_of:1 label:positive
varied_experiences:1 experiences_from:1 island_resident:1 many_and:1 label:positive
scariest:1 many_of:1 label:negative"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep=";", #some string which is NOT in all text
                 header=None, 
                 names=['text'])
print (df)
                                                text
0  really:1 christensen:1 scariest:1 many_of:1 la...
1  varied_experiences:1 experiences_from:1 island...
2                scariest:1 many_of:1 label:negative

df[['bag','label']] = df.text.str.rsplit(expand=True, n=1)
df = df.drop('text', axis=1)
print (df)
                                                 bag           label
0        really:1 christensen:1 scariest:1 many_of:1  label:positive
1  varied_experiences:1 experiences_from:1 island...  label:positive
2                               scariest:1 many_of:1  label:negative
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good trick...But maybe it is difficult to extent it to similar problems. What if there are no the word "label"? But I'll accept your answer as it solves my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I add more general solution.